# Missing libkml required by gdal-3.3.0-r5

Tags: docker, build, dependencies, gdal, alpine-linux

I have a Python project with Docker that uses gdal package. For pretty long time everything were ok, but now I get an error while building an image:

[image]

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6.8-alpine3.10
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
ADD requirements.txt /app/
RUN apk update && \
    apk add \
  --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community \
  --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main \
  geos gdal gdal-dev geos-dev proj-dev && \
  apk add gcc linux-headers musl musl-dev postgresql-dev gdal gdal-dev \
  geos-dev proj-dev zlib-dev jpeg-dev \
  libpng libpng-dev uriparser-dev
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /app/
```

Do anyone know a solution to the problem?

Comment: Could you add your requirements.txt? Without it, it does not reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the old status, but if you search `gdal` in [official package system](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=&path=&name=gdal&branch=v3.10&repo=community&arch=x86_64) now, you will find nothing:

[image]

But, with `alpine3.11`, you could see next:

[image]

So, I guess `gdal` has been deleted from `alpine3.10` official repo, you may have to build it from source code by yourself if you insist work on `alpine3.10` or directly update your base to `python:3.6-alpine3.11`.